# Units of a dual numbers ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are the units of $\mathbb C[\varepsilon]$ ?

$\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ would be the units of $\mathbb C$, I get $3$ other possibilities :

a) $\{a+b\varepsilon\, :\, a,b \in\mathbb C,\ a\ne 0\}$

b) $\{1\}$

c) $\{b\varepsilon\, :\, b \in\mathbb ℂ\setminus\{0\}\ \}$

I would go for (a) but I am not so sure.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: This is the notation for the ring of dual numbers, I assume it's a real number.

Comment: Ok, so $\varepsilon^2=0$, as I've learned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number.

Comment: Why ? I'm not sure I understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(c) cannot be true because $(b\varepsilon)\varepsilon=0$ and no unit can be a zero divisor.

(b) cannot be true because $2$ is a unit.

So, this leaves (a), as you suspected.

Indeed, we can solve
$
1=(a+b\varepsilon)(x+y\varepsilon)=ax+(bx+ay)\varepsilon
$
to get $x=1/a, y=-b/a^2$, provided $a\ne0$.

Or just note that $(a+b\varepsilon)(a-b\varepsilon)=a^2$, from which you can find the inverse given above.

Comment: Great thank you very much, my intuition was related to the form of the set in a). However, I am not sure I understand why c) cannot be true ?

Comment: If $b\varepsilon$ were a unit, we could cancel it in $(b\varepsilon)\varepsilon=0$ and we'd get $\varepsilon=0$.